# C++ Pointer to function call not in scope

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, scope, function-pointers

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I just need some other eyes on this, I have tried everything I can think of, even various random permutations in an attempt to get the compiler to tell me something useful.

Here is where I am at now:

Code:

```
class villain
{
public:
   villain();
   //lots of other stuff
   bool Type1EnemyBlasts();
   bool Type2EnemyBlasts();
   bool (villain::*OnFire)();
};

villain::villain()
{
    //lots of other stuff
    OnFire = &villain::Type1EnemyBlasts;
}

main
{
    //lots and lots of other stuff
    villain *targets[100];
    targets[0] = new villain();
    if(targets[0]->*OnFire() == true)
    {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I call "targets[0]->*OnFire()", where it states that it is not declared in this scope. It feels weird to me that I have to define "OnFire" with "&villain::" when it is being defined inside the villain contructor, but all the information I have found suggests that it must be done this way, and indeed it churns up a whole plethora of errors if I try otherwise.

What is the proper syntax for calling the *OnFire() pointer that belongs to targets[0]?

Comment: No need to use the de-reference operator, just call `targets[0]->OnFire() `

Comment: @wiily That's fine for normal pointers, but not pointers to members.

Comment: Why are you declaring a pointer of an array? Declaring an array already implies that you are declaring a pointer to its first element.

Comment: The required syntax is at least completely unambiguous, if annoying.

Comment: @meross It's an array of pointers. And an array is not a pointer, even if it can decay to one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for calling a pointer to member function is rather atrocious. Here's the correct syntax:

```
if ((targets[0]->*(targets[0]->OnFire))() == true)
```

That is downright ugly. This is why the [Parashift C++ FAQ page on calling pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macro-for-ptr-to-memfn.html) recommends defining a macro for this purpose -- and note that the author of those pages dislikes macros.

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))

...

 if (CALL_MEMBER_FN(*targets[0],targets[0]->OnFire)() == true)
```

Either use a macro or use a `std::function` as described in sehe's answer.

Comment: Holy Moly it compiled.  Ugly it may be, but it works.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3542913 Let me give you a bit of paternal advice. When you are  tempted to write code like this: ***don't do it***. And: **don't** use evil MACROs to make the pain go away. My answer shows the readable version of exactly this: `if ((v.*ptmf)())`...

Comment: Hmm, except you changed your answer below, and I haven't had a chance to try the new revision.  The old revision did not work for me.

Comment: @sehe, there are lots of C++ projects that are perpetually stuck in C++03 land and aren't allowed to use Boost. Calling pointers to member functions is difficult in that world. The correct syntax is so downright ugly (and I said that up front!) that a macro is not a bad alternative.

Comment: @David [`std::function` is part of TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Function_objects). And yes, the macro is still unneeded even without, *[as my answer shows - **Live** On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3e84f58622dd61)* (pure c++03, no TR1).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(targets[0]->*OnFire() == true)
```

to

```
if((targets[0]->*(targets[0]->OnFire))() == true)
```

Since the function call operator, `()`, has higher precedence than `->*`, the first form is interpreted as:

```
if(targets[0]->*(OnFire()) == true)
```

which, as you can see, is not what you want.

Comment: Tried this, and unfortunately returned the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "proper syntax". It would be atrocious (see below)

Use a `std::function` instead:

```
#include <functional>

struct villain
{
    villain();
    //lots of other stuff
    bool Type1EnemyBlasts() {return true;}
    bool Type2EnemyBlasts() {return false;}
    std::function<bool(villain&)> OnFire;
};

villain::villain()
{
    OnFire = &villain::Type1EnemyBlasts;
}

int main()
{
    villain *targets[100];
    targets[0] = new villain();
    villain& v = *targets[0];

    if (v.OnFire(v))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Contrast with the pointer-to-member-function recipe:

```
struct villain
{
    villain();
    //lots of other stuff
    bool Type1EnemyBlasts() {return true;}
    bool Type2EnemyBlasts() {return false;}
    bool (villain::*OnFire)();
};

villain::villain()
{
    //lots of other stuff
    OnFire = &villain::Type1EnemyBlasts;
}

int main()
{
    //lots and lots of other stuff
    villain *targets[100];
    targets[0] = new villain();
    villain& v = *targets[0];

    if ((v.*v.OnFire)())
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlanStokes It seems I don't understand what you are trying to say. FWIW, I test all my code :/

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread what you were doing. The error is entirely mine.

Comment: I think it is odd that you still have to pass `v` again when calling `OnFire` why not just use `function<bool(void)>` and assign it `bind(&villain::Type1EnemyBlasts, this)`?

Comment: First example returns an error of "'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"

Comment: Second example returns ptmf does not name a type, ptmf was not declared in this scope

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose Struct over Class in your examples?

Comment: @user It requires C++11.

Comment: @pmr it was a choice. If you don't bind the object reference, you'll get to chose, exactly like what the OP had, so it's closer to the original and more flexible.

Comment: @AlanStokes It requires c++03 with TR1 (`#include <tr1/function>` and `std::tr1::function<bool(villain&)>` should be fine). Otherwise: boost :)

Comment: @user3542913 I chose struct because you forgot to add `public:` and I'm lazy :)

Comment: @sehe `auto ptmf` wasn't in C++03. (I should have been more precise with "it".)

Comment: @AlanStokes Oh Aha I completely missed the second question.  Well, it's hardly required there anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`(targets[0]->*OnFire)()`

This has some great information on function pointers: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi